# Flickr PHP API help using oAuth?

Tags: php, flickr

I want to get backup of the users photos who has permitted my appication to get Backup. I tried [phpflickr](http://www.phpflickr.com), [phlickr](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phlickr/) and [Pear_Flickr_API](http://code.iamcal.com/php/flickr/readme.htm). Please suggest me which one is better and any tutorial to get started with these.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using phpFlickr.  problem is resolved.